# Does memoization works with active record relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, memoization

Let's say i have a method in my model as below.

```
def all_users 
  @users ||= User.all
end
```

and I have other method in my model where i am doing `all_users.where(id: 123)` for multiple different ids. Will it execute a query/ hit to db everytime or it will fetch the record directly from the cached resultset.

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me. Can you please explain why you want to memorize these queries and elaborate on the actual problem you try to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching) on SQL caching. If the query is exactly the same, the result will be fetched from the cache. Requests for different ID's will result in individual queries.

Be careful when using `#all`, however, as it will load all your records into memory. This can be slow and consume a lot of memory. Making individual `User.find(X)` queries will be better for you in the long run.

Comment: So i have a list of 10 ids and i loop over the ids and execute `all_users.where(id: #id)` it will execute 10 quries ?

Answer (score 2):

`User.all` returns an active record relation - it doesn't fetch any data until you try and do something with it (eg call array-like methods on it). When that happens, rails will load the data for the relation, if it is not already loaded.

So if you do things like

```
all_users.sample(5)
all_users.detect {|record| ... }
```

then you'll only fetch from the data base once.

However if you use methods such as `where`, `joins`, ... that return a new relation then those relations will need to hit the database if their data is needed.

```
all_users.where(id: 1).first
all_users.where(id: 2).first
all_users.where(id: 3).first
```

Would execute 3 queries for example.

If you have a list of ids it would be far better to do `User.find(ids)` (or `User.where(id: ids)` if you want to allow missing values).